# how can i display input to another mxml file in flash builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I display txtName from kuiz.mxml to kuiz1.mxml?
Im new to programming world.Thanks for the help.

kuiz.mxml

```
<s:TextInput x="25" y="112" width="273" prompt="Name" id="txtName" restrict="a-zA-Z"/>
<s:Label id="nameU" x="88" y="175" width="145" text="{txtName.text}" />
```

kuiz1.mxml

```
<s:TextArea id="myTA" x="16" y="336" width="286" height="40" editable="false" prompt="test"/>
```

Comment: How are kuiz and kuiz1 added to the application?

Comment: I have to pass the username value from kuiz.mxml to kuiz1.mxml. Is it possible to pass a value from one MXML to another MXML file? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference in the kuiz.mxml to the kuiz1.mxml i.e.

```
private var kuiz1Displ:kuiz1;
```

1. Create a Bindable variable in kuiz1.mxml i.e.

   [Bindable] public var textDispl:String;
2. Add event listener and event handler to the text input i.e.

   s:TextInput x="25" y="112" width="273" prompt="Name" id="txtName" restrict="a-zA-Z" change="txtName_changeHandler(event)"

   protected function txtName_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
   {
       kuiz1Displ.textDispl = txtName.text;
   }
3. Use the bindable text for you text area in kuiz1 i.e.

   s:TextArea id="myTA" text="{textDispl}" x="16" y="336" width="286" height="40" editable="false" prompt="test"

Remember to assign the kuiz1 to a reference variable during initialisation, now when you change the text in the txtName, the change will be reflected in your kuiz1.

I am sorry I had to omit the opening < and closing /> tags in the mxml code as for some reason the code would not display.